# Activate and Deactivate Mouse Cursor on UI

Tags: unity, c#

I have a player with a character controller component.

When the player is generally interacting with the UI I would like to stop the character and camera controller and show the cursor to the player in order to (e.g select a weapon) and when they're done I would like it to switch back.

How do I address this issue?

Comment: So you just need the mouse cursor to show up when selecting a weapon and then disappear, am i correct? Also which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding your `player` has a First Person Character controller `Component`. You'd need a script sitting on some `GameObject` of your preference and in that script you should follow this logic:

```
public ui_gameobject; //Attach this in the Inspector

//Check if UI is being displayed and handle the cursor
void DetectUIandHandleCursor(){
     if(ui_gameobject.IsActive()){
         Cursor.visible = true;
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
     }else{
         Cursor.visible = false;
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;     
}}
```

I suppose you already have a script managing your `UI` elements (meaning switch them on/off), so the previous snippet should check when you are displaying it and show or hide the cursor accordingly.